# django enum field error when migrating

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using some enum fields in my data model. I've installed django-enumfield package. My django version is 1.10.6 and django-enumfield version is 1.2.1.

Anyway I get the following error when db migration is issued.

> $ **python manage.py makemigrations**

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py3.5.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py3.5.egg/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py3.5.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Django-1.10.6-py3.5.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/indikau/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/indikau/workspace/hotel_manager/manager/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django_enumfield import enum
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_enumfield/enum.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django_enumfield.db.fields import EnumField
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django_enumfield/db/fields.py", line 8, in <module>
    class EnumField(six.with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.IntegerField)):
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'SubfieldBase'
```

Is there anyway to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: All I can say is that enum is evil (yes, please google for that term). So this effort is totally not worth it.

Comment: Any other solution then? It's tedious to use constant values when using select fields.

Comment: enum doesn't really make it easier :)

Answer (score 0):

SubfieldBase was deprecated since 1.8 and it's removed in 1.10.

There looks like a few solutions available here: https://github.com/5monkeys/django-enumfield/issues/39